# Books about investing and finances

Tags: investing, trading, refinance

I'm a python developer and I'm pretty interested in trading. Are there good books on finances and investing for programmers? Or just for beginners? I have studied some economics in college, but not trading. And I want to apply my programming skills in finances. Thanx.

Comment: Dup/overlap of http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7662/resources-for-an-absolute-beginner-to-stocks and half a dozen other questions.  Suggest you read some of them and edit to an actual "new" question.

Comment: @sdg Thanx!I'm now searching for some online video courses either.