# Book recommendation for beginners

Tags: investing, books, recommendation

I am 22 years old and don't know anything about investing, no knowledge whatsoever. I want to learn about it, and the problem is that there are a lot of books in this subject that I don't know where to start at all. So I am looking for book recommendation, or other resources, or suggestions that anyone who has knowledge and experience in it.

I would appreciate if someone can help me by giving suggestions to how to start learning about investment. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you start with The Idiot's Guide to Investing so you can learn about different terms and what type of investments you are interested in so you can then learn more about those subjects.

Comment: This pretty much a duplicate with with question Chris linked.   "A Random Walk Down Wall Street" and the Motley Fool's "How to Invest" are a nice easy to read overviews before diving into the excellent recommendations in that question.

Comment: this is on topic and I am sure has been covered before and good books on investing do not date Securities analysis and Grahams other books for example

Comment: Did you manage to learn anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this page to learn about how portfolio diversification can be done:-

[Super-Efficient Portfolio Applet](http://www.cwgsy.net/private/degnen/investing/theory.html)

Diversification is the safest way to invest and essential to know about.

I would recommend Elton & Gruber's [Modern Portfolio Theory and Investment Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Portfolio-Theory-Investment-Analysis/dp/1118469941/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) but it's rather technical.  Maybe better ideas [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/7677/11768).