# Guidance: New to stock market thing

Tags: investing, stocks, markets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get into investing in stocks?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/how-do-i-get-into-investing-in-stocks)

I am new to stock market, I had just opened up trading account, I will like to know a place from where I can read up the stuff and know how stock market works, what are the factors that effect stock market, so that I can invest wisely.

Thanks in advance 
Sumit Gupta

Comment: Duplicate.  In addition to the duplicate noted above, see also http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/where-to-start-with-personal-finance and http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7662/resources-for-an-absolute-beginner-to-stocks and http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-is-your-favorite-book-on-the-topic-of-investing and http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/best-way-to-start-investing-for-a-young-person-just-starting-their-career

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too broad a question.
To begin with I recommend;

- Read all the questions on this site, more specifically those that are tagged [financial-education](/questions/tagged/financial-education), [books](/questions/tagged/books), [stocks](/questions/tagged/stocks)
- As you are in India, regular read a financial newspaper like Economic Times, or websites like MoneyControl.com and magazines like Outlook Money.

There is no single palce or book that will make you wise over night. Keep working at it for a year or so and you would know substanitally more than today.